# Combining two generics of type Dictionary<string, List<Model>> into another of the same type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have two generics of type `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>` where Person is:

```
Person {
   string FirstName;
   string LastName; 
   List<string> Aliases;
   string Address; 
}
```

One of the generics is a "default" where only FirstName and LastName are filled in. I'll call it "default dictionary" for simplicity... the second dictionary (db dictionary) is filled with values returned from a db call. the key to both dictionaries is "FirstName" from the person object.

Some conditions are that:

- the default dictionary has the correct order of "Person" objects in the list... they are not in alphabetical order or anything like that
- not all "Person" objects in the default list will also be in the db list (the db list person objects will always have a match in the default list though)
- while there are definitely better ways of representing this data... the dictionary types are required to be as they are because I'm passing them to a view that uses foreach loops (nested tables) where the key is the primary table and the list is the rows of the subtables beneath the keys

What I need to do is fill in the addresses and alias lists of the default dictionary Lists for each key with the data that was returned from the db...

I have been able to get both the default and db dictionaries formatted correctly and populated with the correct data (although the lists in the db dictionary are not in the correct order)... I have also been able to "filter" the default dictionary into a new dictionary that only includes keys that are also present in the db dictionary (filtered dictionary)...

What I am having problems with is filling in Person Objects with the address and alias lists for each object returned from the db... I can't just replace the lists because I need to preserve the order of the person objects in the list... here are some code snippets of the last thing that I tried (put the response from the db into a list of all person objects called "responseList")...

```
    Dictionary<string, List<Person>> filteredDictionary = defaultDictionary.Where(x => firstNameList.Contains(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

    foreach (var entry in filteredDictionary)
    {
        var current = entry.Value.ToList();

        current.ForEach(x => responseList.Any(y => y.FirstName == x.FirstName));
        current.ForEach(x => x.Address = responseList.Select(y => y.Address));

    }
```

I know that with LINQ... it's better to just create a new dictionary rather than modify an existing one... but I'm not sure how to get this information into a new dictionary that would preserve the Persons in List order...

Any help would be much appreciated... I've been stuck on this problem for a while.

Comment: I forgot to add that the List<string> of aliases is also returned from the db and needs to be copied over as well

Comment: the Person's in List<Person> for the values of the dictionary are in the correct order, sorry that it was not clear

Comment: Thanks @AleksAndreev I edited the question

Comment: Would you be looking for `.Concat()`?

Comment: What is a "generic"? Note that there is no order to the members of a `Dictionary` object. Your `Person` class has no modifiers or `public` fields - how do you expect to set values for it?

Comment: You say the key is the `FirstName` of the `Person` object - does that mean there are multiple `Person` objects with the same `FirstName`, and if so, how do you know which one matches? If not, why do you have a `List<Person>` in the `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should know, that a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) doesn't ensure a specific order:

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Nevertheless, the current implementation seems to return the values in the same order as they have been given. But their is no guarantee for that. If you need a specific order, you should use a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) and provide a desired comparer.

With this informations given, here is an example on how you update your default dictionary with the values from the database dictionary.

```
// Create some sample data, we can use
var persons = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => new Person
    {
        FirstName = $"FirstName {i}",
        LastName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Address = $"Address {i}",
        Aliases = Enumerable
            .Range(i * 100, i)
            .Select(j => $"Alias {i} - {j}")
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();

// Create the default dict, (hopefully) ordered by Firstname
var defaultDict = persons.ToDictionary(
    person => person.FirstName,
    person => new Person
    {
        FirstName = person.FirstName,
        LastName = person.LastName
    });

// Create the default dict, (hopefully) ordered by Lastname
var dbDict = persons
    .OrderBy(person => person.LastName)
    .ToDictionary(person => person.FirstName);

Console.WriteLine("Default dictionary");
foreach (var person in defaultDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{person.Value.FirstName} {person.Value.LastName} {person.Value.Address ?? "No address" }");
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("DB dictionary");
foreach (var person in dbDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{person.Value.FirstName} {person.Value.LastName} {person.Value.Address ?? "No address" }");
}

// Iterate over the db entries and update all default entries
foreach (var item in dbDict)
{
    if(defaultDict.TryGetValue(item.Key, out Person defaultPerson))
    {
        defaultPerson.Address = item.Value.Address;
        defaultPerson.Aliases = item.Value.Aliases.ToList();
    }
}

// Show updated default dictionary
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Updated default dictionary");
foreach (var person in defaultDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{person.Value.FirstName} {person.Value.LastName} {person.Value.Address ?? "No address" }");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve my problem based off of your answer! I was having some problems wording my question because I was trying to stay within the constraints of an NDA, I'm sorry for the confusion!